# Calendar-based heatmap for Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, calendar, heatmap

I have developed an web app using Angular 2 (using Angular CLI) and I would like to implement a calendar-based heatmap using Angular 2 / Typescript. Examples are below:

https://github.com/g1eb/angular-calendar-heatmap

https://github.com/wa0x6e/cal-heatmap

(or see the contribution calendar on GitHub)

The first link above appears to work for AngularJS (although I haven't tested this) however I'm not sure of what needs to be done to convert this to Angular 2 (or if it is even possible).

Does anyone know what my options are for implementing a calendar-based heatmap using Angular 2 / Typescript?

Comment: You probably could find this useful: https://github.com/g1eb/angular2-calendar-heatmap

Comment: @UrbanCondor did you find a solution? I am currently trying to get it to work on my project, but no success so far.